# UINavigationController facing some problems

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have UIView controller class where i have programmatically created a UINAvigationController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
  {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Hmm";


navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
//without this instruction, the tableView appears blocked
navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004); // <-- nav controller should fill the screen
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
navigationController.title = @"Hello";
[navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 70, 200, 50);
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = frame;
[button setTitle:@"Bejoy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:button];

    }
```

Now in the button click event

```
-  (void)myButtonClick:(id)sender {
SAPRetailExCustomerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC *customerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC = [[SAPRetailExCustomerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SAPRetailExCustomerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC" bundle:nil];
[navigationController pushViewController:customerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC animated:YES];
[customerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC release]; 
            }
```

Here in the output the view is navigating but the button remains in my view!!!
Also i have to click twice to get the back button in my NavigationController.
Is it because i don't have a title for my navigation bar. How will i set the title here?.
Can someone help me??

Comment: "`[[UINavigationController alloc] init]`" Why are you doing this? Just use `UINavigationController` the way it was meant to be used: either `initWithRootViewController:`, or make one in Interface Builder and set its `Nib Name` to your controller class. Never create one with `init`, `init` is not present in the class documentation so you shouldn't think you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your UIViewcontroller should be the child of the navigation controller and not the other way round. Your UIViewController is not responsible for its own navigation controller.

Use UINavigationController's -initWithRootViewController: where you create your UIViewController object and add the navigation controller's view to the window.

What you are doing is wrong: You add the navigation controller's view to the view controller's one!

Comment: which rootview controller should i use?. I want to navigate from SAPRetailExCustomerDetailViewTVC -> SAPRetailExCustomerSalesOrderDetailViewTVC where both are of UIViewController.

Comment: Nopes Sry i got it... I added SAPRetailExCustomerDetailViewTVC as my root wiew controller for my UINAvigationController. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nopes Sry i got it... I added SAPRetailExCustomerDetailViewTVC as my root wiew controller for my UINAvigationController. Thanks a lot

SAPRetailExCustomerDetailViewTVC *customerDetailViewTVC = [[SAPRetailExCustomerDetailViewTVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SAPRetailExCustomerDetailViewTVC" bundle:nil]; // Update the split view controller's view controllers array. newdetailViewController = customerDetailViewTVC; UINavigationController *cusotmerDetailNavigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newdetailViewController ];

Comment: In IB it's easier to setup a navigation Controller but great it's working now.